# Java map value returns null

Tags: java, dictionary, null

I have kind of a really strange problem. I have a simple Map called vectors where I store StrategyPairs as keys and Vectors as the values. When I print it, I get this result:

```
{net.softwarepage.facharbeit.normalgame.logic.StrategyPair@131e56d7=(1.0;2.0), net.softwarepage.facharbeit.normalgame.logic.StrategyPair@1e1bc985=(2.0;2.0), net.softwarepage.facharbeit.normalgame.logic.StrategyPair@d5415975=(0.0;2.0), net.softwarepage.facharbeit.normalgame.logic.StrategyPair@5bf8c6e7=(2.0;1.0)}
```

As you can see `StrategyPair@131e56d7` is mapped to a Vector (1,2).
Now I create a new StrategyPair. When I print it I get `StrategyPair@131e56d7` (the same one as before).
However, if I now call `vectors.get(strategyPair)` it returns null.
This is somehow really strange as the key is the same (at least it prints the exact same thing out when I print it...)

The problem arises when I rename a strategy, e.g. I change the property name in the class "Strategy". Then suddenly the map which contains StrategyPairs (a wrapper class for two strategies) is messed up as I explained before...

EDIT:
When I print the HashMap I still get the same result as above, but the following code:

```
for(StrategyPair pair : vectors.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(vectors.get(pair));
}
```

returns:
null
(2.0;2.0)
null
(2.0;1.0)

Comment: What kind of map? How do you think the map should identify two equal keys?

Comment: @mathiasj Can you please implement `toString()` on your `StartegyPair` class? It is possible for two elements to have the same hash but not be equal.

Comment: Did you override equals and hashcode?

Comment: It's a Hashmap.
With toString overwritten, I get this result:
`{OBEN + links=(1.0;2.0), unten + rechts=(2.0;2.0), OBEN + rechts=(0.0;2.0), unten + links=(2.0;1.0)}
OBEN + links
null`

for this code: 
`System.out.println(vectors);
        StrategyPair pair = new StrategyPair(...);
        System.out.println(pair);
        System.out.println(vectors.get(pair));`

Yes, equals and hashcode are both overwritten.

Comment: This is a not a HashMap. Please add your implementation of StrategyPair.

Comment: private final HashMap<StrategyPair, Vector> vectors = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The hashcode of your keys should not change after you keep them in the map. If you change any of the properties of your object which effect the hashcode, then this behaviour can occur. Ideally keys should be immutable

Comment: This is my implementation of StrategyPair: http://pastebin.com/hEEWrzuD

@RajendraGujja But I need to change the name of the strategy so the property of the key (and hence the hashcode) will change. What should I do then? But this makes some sense.

Comment: Add also Strategy implementation. You hashcode implementation related to this class.

Comment: Strategy: http://pastebin.com/hKeEcbwN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rajendra Gujja mentioned in a comment, the "hashcode of your keys should not change after you keep them in the map". This is very true; once I changed all the hashcodes to simply use a UUID instead of the name property which changes, the problem is solved. Thanks for all of your answers!